# Why are Comodore James Norrington and Weatherby Swann the same just as young, but Elizabeth Swann and Will Turner change their age respectively?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, curse-of-the-black-pearl

In the start of Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl, both characters have this supposed age. Here are pictures of Comodore Norrington and Weatherby Swann in the opening scene and the rest of the movie respectively:

[image]
[image: photo2]

The only change appreciable is the gray color in their hairs, but Elizabeth Swann and Will Turner are very young compared with the other two.. There have passed over 15-20 years. If Elizabeth Swann would have been 8-12 years, the Comodore would have been 20-35 years...

> Comodoro: 20-33 years + 15+20 years (the time that could have passed)
>   = **35-53** years
>
> Elizabeth: 8-12 + 15+20 = 23-**32 years**
>
> Weatherby Swann: 40-49 + 15+20 = 55-**69 years**.
>
> Actual Years of Jonathan Pryce (Weatherby Swann): **69 years**.
>
> Actual Years of Jack Davenport (Comodore): **44 years**.

I supposed that the time that could have passed are 20 years but the Comodore doesn't  comply this because he is younger than 35 years in the film.

Why are Comodore James Norrington and Weatherby Swann the same just as young, but Elizabeth Swann and Will Turner change their age respectively?

Comment: It's only been ten years... that hair is fake... they are wearing wigs because that's what was standard at the time. The color is their choice.

Comment: so, which is the elizabeth age in the opening scene?

Comment: She started out as an eight year old and is 18 when she's older...

Comment: Actually, according to Wikipedia it's only 8 years. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirates_of_the_Caribbean:_The_Curse_of_the_Black_Pearl

Comment: keira knightley in this film is like a young girl(i say in face)...

Comment: So? 8-10 year olds change how they look a lot. Puberty changes a lot. You really don't want to cast an adult to play a kid, regardless of how childlike they look.

Comment: yes is alright..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a person is fully grown, their physical appearance doesn't change all that much, aside from greying hair and (perhaps) added weight.  As my father likes to say: "you've stopped growing *up* and started growing *out*!"

Because of this, it's relatively simple to change the apparent age of an actor who's character is fully grown in both "past" and "present" scenes.  for example, Swann and Weatherby were both adults in the opening scene, and only got older for the rest of the film, so adjusting the apparent age of the actors is easy.

However, for characters who are young children in one scene and adult later (like Elizabeth) this can't be done so easily.  No (feasible) amount of makeup is going to make a 20 year old actress look like she's 8.  Therefore, they need to hire a second actress to play the "young Elizabeth" role.

**TLDR**

It's a limitation of what can be accomplished with makeup and special effects touch-ups.  The reason for the dramatic changes in Will Turner and Elizabeth Swann between these two scenes is simply down to the fact that they needed to use different actors in each time period.

Comment: yes and if they were found somepeople that look like Comodore Norrington and Weatherby Swann would have delayed many time.